# How to enable cors in Vercel

Tags: cors, vercel

I've been trying to find a solution to the CORS error I currently have in my app, It's a VueJS project with no backend. I'm aware of the cors-anywhere proxy, but I can't use it because it changes the locality of the API, I've also tried using a vercel.json file but I still get the error:
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.deezer.com/infos' from origin 'https://syren-test.vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

How do I fix it please

Comment: Breaking my head the same issue, if you get any solution please tell

Comment: @GayatriDipali how did your head go on this? Mine still hurts

Comment: I fixed it by creating my own nodejs proxy server with cors enabled.
I use it for almost all my projects with cors issues